# Use regex to capture a string that has special characters

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I am trying to use regex to parse a string and extract the required data. Here's my string:

> Validate control value for ELEMENT - VerifyFirstRowSearchNotes as
>   ~Creating Stat Reserve: ~IP: Claimant Driver; IP Role(s): Owner,
>   Driver~Exposure

I am trying to capture the data using the below regex pattern. I am interested in the data that follows "as" in particular. However, I am only able to capture control value below and not able to extract anything after "as" and assign it to fields group:

```
string actionpattern = @"Validate control value for ELEMENT - (?<control>.*?)as (?<fields>.*?)";
var regex = new Regex(actionpattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = regex.Match({above string});
```

Let me know what I have been doing wrong. I am new to regex and in the process of learning.

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Ah yes of course. If you remove the questionmark `(?<fields>.*?)` you will make it greedy and match everything after as `(?<fields>.*)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My expected results should be
match.Groups["control"] = VerifyFirstRowSearchNotes
match.Groups["fields"] = ~Creating Stat Reserve: ~IP: Claimant Driver; IP Role(s): Owner, Driver~Exposure

Comment: So, you should use `(?<fields>.*)`

Comment: See [What do 'lazy' and 'greedy' mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the link mate. I will go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the question mark in this part `(?<fields>.*?)` you will make it greedy and match everything after as `(?<fields>.*)`

Your regex would look like:

[`Validate control value for ELEMENT - (?<control>.*?)as (?<fields>.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/4ZWsOc/1)

Comment: Ah! that was a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. Its working.